# Como puedo quitar esos fastidiosos rectangulos que envuelven mi codigo

Tags: sublimetext3

Estoy empezando a programar en python usando sublime text 3, Creo que al instalar anaconda aca en sublime comenzaron a aparecer esa especie de rectángulos que me molestan al ver el codigo. Me pueden decir como eliminarlos porfavor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres deshablitar solo esta opción sin deshabilitar las otras opciones que  ofrece el plugin de anaconda

Ve a `Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings - User`. Luego pega el siguiente código y dale clic a guardar:

```
{
     "pep8": false,
}
```

Esto desactivará completamente las ayudas del pep8 para formatos de archivos python

Por ultimo dale `control + s` o `cmd + s` o `File → Save`, para guardar.
Espero que esto te solucione el problema

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tienes instalado el Anaconda package.

`control + shift + p` o `cmd + shift + p` y escribe `control:disable package` y luego escribe `sublimelinter` y dale clic. Si no funciona entonces, escribe `anaconda` y dale clic a `disable`.

Si lo anterior no funciona entonces, ve a `Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings-User`. Luego pega el siguiente código y dale clic a guardar:

```
{
    "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```